# Authenticating a user in a MVC application using JSON Web Tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, jwt

I have a legacy application from which I want to spawn a session in a new asp.net MVC application.  I am attempting to pass a JSON Web Token to the MVC application to authenticate the user.  I have it working for the most part, but it is requiring some extra code to get the user signed in (using Request.GetOwinContext().ctx.Authentication.SignIn) .  It is making me question whether I am going down the correct path.

From what I have read I would think that I should be able to use the ClaimsPrincipal object created by the ValidateToken method to sign the user into the application.

My Issues:

1. The ClaimsIdentity instance created by ValidateToken sets the Authentication Type to Federated.  To sign the user into the MVC application, I need to set the authentication type to Cookies (I think).  To do this I am creating a new ClaimsIdentity instance based off the one created by ValidateToken and then passing ApplicationCookie as the authentication type to the constructor.  Is it necessary to be doing this and is there a way to change the authentication type on the original ClaimsIdentity instance without creating a new one?
2. I cannot get the name property to be set automatically by the ValidateToken method.  The SignIn method seems to require that to be set.  To get around this I set it explicitly by pulling the name claim from the ClaimsIdentity instance created by ValidateToken (`ident2.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, myIdentity.FindFirstValue("Name")));`).  Is there a claim I can pass in the payload of the JWT that will be mapped to this property automatically?

Or in general is this the wrong approach to accomplish the authentication?

The claims set of the payload for my JWT looks something like:

```
{
  "iss": "http://oldapp.testing.com",
  "aud": "http://newapp.testing.com",
  "sub": "99239",
  "iat": 1425507035,
  "exp": 1425507065,
  "name": "First Last",
  "role": [
    "Admin"
  ]
```

And the C# code to process it:

```
        JwtSecurityToken tokenReceived = new JwtSecurityToken(token);

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler recipientTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("someTestSecretKeyForTestingThis");
        if (keyBytes.Length < 64 && tokenReceived.SignatureAlgorithm == "HS256")
        {
            Array.Resize(ref keyBytes, 64);
        }


        TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidIssuer = "http://oldapp.testing.com",
            ValidAudience = "http://newapp.testing.com",
            IssuerSigningToken = new BinarySecretSecurityToken(keyBytes)
        };

        try
        {
            SecurityToken validatedToken;
            var principal = recipientTokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);

            // Pull out the ClaimIdentity created by ValidateToken
            var myIdentity = principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault();

            //
            // Copy ClaimIdentity created by the ValidateToken method and change the Authentication
            // type from Federated to Cookie
            //
            // Is there a better way to do this???
            //
            var ident2 = new ClaimsIdentity(myIdentity.Claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            //
            // Make sure the Name claim is set correctly so that the SignIn method will work
            //
            // Why isn't the Name claim set automatically???
            //
            ident2.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, myIdentity.FindFirstValue("Name")));

            // Sign the user in
            var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
            var authManager = ctx.Authentication;
            authManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            authManager.SignIn(ident2);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception :" + ex.Message);
```